# getting "Access is denied" message when trying to run app on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

C:\Users\ANKUR SINGH.gradle\caches\6.5\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

above message is coming
I also tried deleting cache file still didn't work
[this is the screen shot of same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUyOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
- Shutdown Android Studio
- Rename/remove the .gradle folder in the user home directory
- Restart Android Studio (It will download Gradle metadata and data)

**Gradle build succeed**

**Rebuild project. Done.**

***EDIT
Try this for Mac OS
Go to SDK manager (with Administrator rights), scroll down till the end, download "Android Support Library".***